# Kendo ui Grid row undo delete

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I am not deleting when there is only one row in the grid. But when I click on grid row delete button when grid is on inline edit mode it removes the row from the grid but when I do not really not delete the row from the server grid does not show that row again.
I have seen examples people do this by using  grid.cancelChanges();
But how the grid knows that I have not deleted the record at the server side.

How can I achieve this please help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this setting a Model error manually at the code.

Information on this link helped me.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/grid/add-and-update-still-show-entry-even-when-model-errors-are-returned.aspx